# What kind of camera bag would I look for to allow fast lens swaps?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-bag, event, changing-lenses

I might get a chance to go to some fun events to take pictures soon, and I'd rent a lens or two to take with me (as this doesn't happen enough to justify buying a decent wide angle). However, this is an event situation, and I'd like to be able to switch between the lenses quickly. Thus, it would be nice if I had some way to carry 2 lenses, in such a way that they could be swapped out on a camera, without having to find a table somewhere to set down a traditional "backpack" or similar. It doesn't need to have space for the camera itself; that'll be attached to me via neck strap.

Does such a tool or bag exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### [Lowepro S&F belt system](http://products.lowepro.com/product/S-F-Deluxe-Waistbelt,2026.htm)

This system of belt and pouches provides a soultion to lens storeage needs withour requiring a bag as such.

You would use pouches to store lenses attached to the belt, when you need to change lens, take it off pop it in a pouch, take the other lens out and pop it on.

This system also means that you do not need to have the lens caps on as the pouches are very good and close to keep dust away.

### [Think Tank Speed Changer](http://www.thinktankphoto.com/products/speed-changer-v2.aspx)

Similar system to the Lowepro belts, this pouch holds 2 lenses or a lens and a pro DSLR. This way you can take off a les pop in in a slot, take the other lens out of the other slot pop it on and close the pouch.

Comment: Specifically, check out the S&F lens exchange case:  http://products.lowepro.com/product/SF-Lens-Exchange-Case-200-AW,2226,53.htm

Comment: so, most of my lenses came with lens cases that have a belt loop.  Whats the difference between the belt system and just sticking those on a normal belt?

Comment: Good question! a normal belt may not be strong enough to stay in position on your waist. These systems have strong materials designed to carry quite some weight, while keeping the belt both comfortable and in position, if you use a regular belt, you risk your trousers falling down with the weight.

Comment: Just and idea - as the photo carrying systems are relatively expensive, there may be a possibility to use a tactical vest or something similar from some army sell-off, which is also designed to carry heavy items and the military look should be no problem as these things are mostly used for traveling and outdoor photo.

Comment: @GraemeHutchison - Ah, not a problem for me then - I almost always wear perry suspenders (seriously) http://perrysuspenders.com/persus.html

Answer (score 4):

There are two types I know of

**Sling Backpack**

These you wear like a backpack, but they are made so that you can twist them around to your side or front to easily remove a camera or extra lens.  Popular ones are made by [Kata](http://www.kata-bags.com/3n1-20-for-dslr-w-mid-range-zoom-lens-3-4-lenses-flash) and [Lowepro](http://products.lowepro.com/catalog/Sling-bags,4.htm)

**Rotating Belt Pack**

I've seen these before, not sure which model, but like this one from [Think Tank](http://www.thinktankphoto.com/products/rotation360-backpack.aspx).  They are like a normal backpack, but the bottom part, a sort of pouch, can be rotated along the belt to your front.

Or as drewbenn said, belt-mounted lens cases.  If you just want an extra lens, that's the easiest and probably cheapest way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Another bag type that MikeW didn't mention is the messenger bag style, like the [Lowepro Exchange Messenger](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002PK14VC) or the [Tamrac Rally 5](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0045NYLT4). They'll generally hold 2-5 lenses and a camera body, and give you quick, one-handed access to your gear. They also don't look too much like camera bags. On the flip side, they'll swing around when you lean forward and they can make one of your shoulders sore.

Answer (score 1):

you can also just buy two Tamrac or Lowepro lens cases and put them on some sturdy belt - both companies have some system for carrying these cases (belt or something like a tactical vest), but it should be also usable with other (maybe military) equipment.

My [Tamrac MX5378 M.A.S. Lens Case](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/198712-REG/Tamrac_MX537801_MX5378_M_A_S_Lens_Case.html) for example, has also something like standard belt loop so I do not have to use the Tamrac carrying system necessarily.

And finally, you can choose something like my Lowepro Inverse 100 AW which I described [in this thread](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18535/what-kind-of-camera-bag-should-i-pick-for-traveling-around-the-alps/18546#18546). I t has removable separators inside so you can use it for camera and lenses or only for lenses - depends on you. But you should take it into account that in most cases it is better to carry the camera in some bag/case and not on the neck - at least for better protection.