# How to carry a DSLR on a motorcycle?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, equipment-protection, travel, transport

I do a lot of road trips and I carry my camera (D90+50mm) and an extra lens (18-105mm) in my backpack ([Lowpro CompuDaypack](http://products.lowepro.com/product/CompuDaypack,1922,16.htm)). The backpack is great, but it doesn't allow me to draw my cam out quickly to capture a quick moment. I tried hanging the camera to my neck and that felt too dangerous!

I was wondering whether there is any other type of camera bag or holder with the "quick draw" feature. Also, I would prefer if it can be attached to my bike itself or if it can be kept on the front side of my body (as opposed to the backpack).

I also have a tripod (Slik F133) which came with a pouch that i use to carry on my shoulder (very uncomfortable) as it doesn't fit in my backpack. Is there any more convenient way to carry it? "quick draw" feature is not required for this one though.

Comment: Some suggestions here that may be helpful(quick draw feature): http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18785/what-kind-of-camera-bag-would-i-look-for-to-allow-fast-lens-swaps

Comment: Try motorcycle transport case on eBay pdmts makes a great system I love it

Comment: For safety's sake, I recommend against carrying equipment attached to you.  Anything large and solid (tripod, camera body) between you and an impact surface is going to cause additional injury during a crash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about buying a decent sized tank bag and padding that out a bit? If you use a magnetic tank bag you might have to be mindful of where they are in relation to the camera gear although they don't usually seem to be under the bag itself, rather on flaps to the sides.

You could keep the camera sat in there with quite a long lens on it (most tank bags are fairly long) so the lens faces away from you. Once you have stopped unzipping and drawing your camera will be about as quick as you can get whilst keeping your camera safe during the journey...

A chap appears to have tried it [here](http://www.eos-images.com/tips-techniques/converting-a-motorcycle-tank-bag-into-a-photography-bag).

Some tank bags can be quite large - I used to ride with one about this size without any issues: [link](http://www.webbikeworld.com/r2/motorcycle-tank-bag/motorcycle-tank-bag-expanded.jpg)

Or something like [this](http://essentialgearguide.com/tag/motorcycle-tank-bag/) or [this](http://www.touratech-usa.com/Store/PN-055-1077/Photographer-Tank-bag-Large-camera)

Answer (score 1):

You will like the cotton carrier. I use it on my bike and the camera Canon 5DM2 with a 70-200mm L 2.8II has never felt safer. There is a locking mechanism where The camera comes out only if tilted a certain way and also has a flap that goes over the lens so the it does not swing around. This setup has been the fastest for me to take the camera off to shoot and then put it back on the harness. Of course your camera is out in the open since its not  a case but I also use neoprene cases that prevent dust or stones that might hit the camera....then my top speed on the bike is about 15-20mph tops! Check it out to see if it fits your needs!

Answer (score 1):

I used a Kata 3N1 whilst cycling - with a single strap and the waist belt, this was quite quick and felt secure. You can get an optional tripod holder for this bag that will work with a smallish tripod

I would also recommend using a toploader type holster with a chest harness.

Answer (score 0):

what about some "pistol" aka topload case only for the camera with attached lens + your current backpack for additional accessories?

I recommend CaseLogic - they have very good and tough cases with hard plastic shell bottom - something like [this](http://www.caselogic.com/slr_zoom_holster/product_detail/index.cfm?modelid=133826&productid=1347175#). Much quicker to pull out the camera than backpack.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite happy with [Lowepro Fastpack](http://products.lowepro.com/product/Fastpack-250,2086,14.htm) -- it's a backpack with a pistol-like compartment on a side that allows you to easily draw camera with the backpack still hanging on your left shoulder. (Haven't used it on a motorcycle though.)

Answer (score 0):

For similar situations bicycle riding I have had success carrying an SLR using a LowePro TLZ1 attached to the straps of a camelback using mini-carabiners. Can just about be made out in this photo on flickr: http://www.flickr.com/photos/tomlevell/118201961/in/photosof-nickw3216/

The modern equivalent is a Toploader zoom: http://www.lowepro.com/toploaderzoom.

Caveat: don't even think about the consequences of falling off and landing on your chest; if someone comes up with an on-bike solution (Oxford tankbag?) that would be a lot safer.

Answer (score 0):

With a little modification to minimize center of gravity issues this might work. You could keep your rig right in front of you and have instant access. Of course you loose some protection and the extreme wind may harm the camera. Still, if you have a windshield on your bike it may work just fine. Have fun!

Lowepro S&F Technical Harness
[google product search](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=camera%20harness%20for%20professional&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=3707278993528365189&sa=X&ei=2iwHT86gHpP9iQKFx7WoCQ&ved=0CHEQ8wIwBQ)

Answer (score 0):

For instant access to your camera (faster than any bag or topload case), you may consider a
[spider holster](http://www.spiderholster.com/).
I have successfully used it on a bicycle, locked to my belt (not the spider holster belt).

I do not ride motorbikes however: for a biker’s perspective, take a look at
[this review](http://www.mototrip.org/2011/11/10/gear-review-spider-holster/).